# Aws ImportImageTask failed with internal error 500

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS(Amazon Web Service) and also to AWS sdk (JAVA). Initially i was trying to find how to create VM with aws sdk in amazon but a couldn't found any way for it.
I found anther solution that is use EC2 `Imageimport` can create VM in AWS with your local disk so i am trying to implement the flow for it but is failing with internal Error below

> Error Message:    An internal error has occurred (Service: AmazonEC2;
>   Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalError; Request ID:
>   c3bab0f1-d70a-4c72-ba91-21004045088a) HTTP Status Code: 500 AWS Error
>   Code:   InternalError Error Type:       Unknown Request ID:
>   c3bab0f1-d70a-4c72-ba91-21004045088a

any one who is families with AWS please help me out and if any one knows the way to create VM in AWS with disk uploaded in bucket please share it. 
Below is what i tried.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.regions.ServiceAbbreviations;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2AsyncClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.ImageDiskContainer;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.ImportImageRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.UserBucket;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;

public class SSBucketFinder {
    static AmazonS3 s3;
    static AmazonEC2 ec2;
    static AWSCredentials credentials = null;

    private static void init() throws Exception {
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("#################",
                "###############################");
        s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        ec2 = new AmazonEC2AsyncClient(credentials);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("List of buckets:");
        init();
        try {
            List<Bucket> buckets = s3.listBuckets();
            for (Bucket bucket : buckets) {
                System.out.println(bucket.getName());
            }
        } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
        }
        UserBucket ub = new UserBucket();
        ub.setS3Bucket("surebkt1");
        ImportImageRequest iir = new ImportImageRequest();
        Collection<ImageDiskContainer> diskContainers = new ArrayList<ImageDiskContainer>();
        ImageDiskContainer idc = new ImageDiskContainer();
        idc.setDeviceName("C:\\ubuntuminimal\\87EA3BAC-A8C0-4F76-ACA8-FE440C5C7B85_1.vhd");
        idc.setFormat("vhd");
        idc.setUserBucket(ub);
        diskContainers.add(idc);
        iir.setDiskContainers(diskContainers);
        iir.setArchitecture("x86_64");
        iir.setDescription("Import Task");
        iir.setHypervisor("xen");
        iir.setRequestCredentials(credentials);
        iir.setPlatform("linux");
        try {
            System.out.println("EC2 Import image");
            ec2.importImage(iir);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are not meeting one or more of the requirements mentioned here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/VMImportPrerequisites.html#vmimport-limitations